# Scope of variable declared in condition

Tags: c++, scope

Some refactoring led to a piece of code that led me to this minimal testcase:

```
int main () {
    if (int i=1) {
        /* IF-BLOCK */
    } else {
        throw i;
    }
}
```

This compiles fine. However, I always assumed that `i` is only visible to `IF-BLOCK`, but it seems that it's not. Is this a compiler bug?

Also, why does the following work?

```
int main () {
    if (int i=1) {
    } else if (int i=2) {
    } else {
        throw i;
    }
}
```

Note the second `if` "re-declares" `i`. Another compiler bug?

Comment: This is a very useful feature in C++. I think the main usecase people had in mind is something like `if (auto p = dynamic_cast<Foo*>(q)) { /* ... use p ... */ }`, or any kind of situation where a pointer is created that may be null.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No, this is actually correct behavior.

> #### 6.4 Selection statements [stmt.select]
>
> **A name introduced by a declaration in a condition** (either introduced by the `type-specifier-seq` or the declarator of the condition) **is in scope from its point of declaration until the end of the substatements** controlled
>   by the condition. **If the name is re-declared in the outermost block** of a substatement controlled by the
>   condition, **the declaration** that re-declares the name is **ill-formed.** [ Example:
>
> ```
> if (int x = f()) {
>     int x; // ill-formed, redeclaration of x
> }
> else {
>     int x; // ill-formed, redeclaration of x
> }
> ```
>
> — end example ]

(Emphasis mine)

This basically means that the scope of `i` begins in the condition, and ends after the `if`-block, where the `else`-block is part of the `if`-block, too.

Your second problem with the nested `if` is based on the (wrong) assumption that an `else-if` is part of the introductory `if`, but it really isn't. The `if (int i=2)` is *the body of the first `else`*!

```
     if (int i=1)
          |
         / \
        /   \
       /     \
      /       \
     /         \
   if-block   else
               |
           if(int i=2)
             /    \
            /      \
           /        \
       if-block   throw i
```

What this means in turn:

```
int main () {
    if (int i=1) {    
    } else if (1) {
        throw (i+2);
    } else {
        throw i;
    }
}
```

This code is valid, as the `i`-declaration is visible in `throw (i+2);`, but it is still valid to hide the first `i`, because in nested scopes, names can be overriden:

```
int main () {
    if (int i=1) {    
    } else if (int i=2) {
        throw (i+2); // now refers to `int i=2`
    } else {
        throw i;
    }
}
```

So all in all, don't panic: Writing tokenizers or parsers or something using the pattern found in the last statement still works, the relevant new knowledge here is that any declaration in a condition spans the whole `if`-tree, but can be overriden in any nested `if`.

Also, be assured that the following is still invalid (even though it was valid in old compilers):

```
if (int i=0) {}
std::cout << i; // nope, not valid
```

Comment: +1 had never thought about this, good to know. Is there a story behind this, or did you just want to share something you dug up due to academic interest?

Comment: @Hulk: I dug to it while refactoring some hobby code, where a variable was still accessible even though I removed its declaration, right before driving to my real workplace :). You can see the actual change there: https://github.com/phresnel/excygen/commit/cafbe02a9d0d598b3455c80444fe2978f52716c1#L0L138 . Initially, there was just `if (auto oit = operator_(it, end))`, then I removed that by something like `if (*it == '/')`, but inside its block, it still accessed `oit`, it compiled, but I got an exception for unitialized `optional<>`, and this all is what I found out and wanted to share :)